# Writing a sample server app - is forkIO unavoidable?

Tags: networking, haskell, concurrency

I haven't done anything networkish in haskell, so I'm giving that a try now. I'm using Oleg's ZFS as a template how to do that.

IIRC he wasn't using threads but was using "delimited continuations" instead so I wonder if a heavier load server app could principally also be written without using forkIO threads.

Günther

Answer (score 2):

This is really a research question. Oleg's zipperFS didn't use any of Haskell's fine concurrency mechanisms under  the hood, so it wouldn't scale to many concurrent users, I'm quite certain.

I'm intrigued that you can write a web server using a zipper. Publish!

But why not just write a regular server using massive concurrency in the classic style -- one forkIO per accept?

Comment: Dear Don,
I'm really just experimenting at this time.
Another point is that I'm trying to stay "functional" as much as possible and even Haskell98-ish as much as possible too until I hit the point where it just doesn't make sense any more from a practical point of view. (Which of course could be fairly quick).

When it comes to Olegs work and research that seems to be his overall theme and he succeeds fairly often with it too. There are a couple of accomplished Haskellers who also try to keep it this way, Luke Palmer et al for example.

Günther